# Reading from a depth texture in a fragment shader

Tags: java, opengl, shader, textures, depth-buffer

I have a depth texture defined as the following:

```
    //shadow FBO and texture
    depthFBO = new FrameBufferObject().create().bind();
    depthTexture = new Texture2D().create().bind()
            .storage2D(12, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, 4096, 4096)
            .minFilter(GL_LINEAR)
            .magFilter(GL_LINEAR)
            .compareMode(GL_COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE)
            .compareFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    depthFBO.texture2D(GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture, 0)
            .checkStatus().unbind();
    depthTexture.unbind();
```

It's written in Java/LWJGL/Own small framework, but the idea should be clear.

Then I use a fragment shader at some point to visualize the data in it (fragment's depth):

```
#version 430 core

layout(location = 7) uniform int screen_width;
layout(location = 8) uniform int screen_height;

layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2D shadow_tex;

out vec4 color;

void main(void) {
    vec2 tex_coords = vec2(
        (gl_FragCoord.x - 100) / (screen_width / 5),
        (gl_FragCoord.y - (screen_height - (screen_height / 5) - 100)) / (screen_height / 5)
    );
    float red_channel = texture(shadow_tex, tex_coords).r;
    if (red_channel < 0.999) {
        red_channel = red_channel / 2.0;
    }
    color = vec4(vec3(red_channel), 1.0);
}
```

My `tex_coords` and `shadow_tex` are correct, but I need some more clarification on reading out of a `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F` format.

I want to read the depth and I assume it is being stored being 0.0 and 1.0 in 4 bytes of float values.

So I was *thinking* I can use the red channel of what `texture` gives me back, however I cannot see a difference in depth. Other than it not being 1.0 exactly, but somewhat lower. If I do not divide by 2.0, then everything appears white.

[image: screenshot]

Note that the floor is black at some points, but that is due to a failed shadow mapping, hence why I am visualizing it - however it is temporarily set to use the normal view MVP instead of the light's, to also make sure the depth information is saved correctly.

**UPDATE**: The colorization of the depth value is now working correctly with the following:

```
#version 430 core

layout(location = 7) uniform int screen_width;
layout(location = 8) uniform int screen_height;

layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2D shadow_tex;

out vec4 color;

float linearize_depth(float original_depth) {
    float near = 0.1;
    float far = 1000.0;
    return (2.0 * near) / (far + near - original_depth * (far - near));
}

void main(void) {
    //calculate texture coordinates, based on current dimensions and positions of the viewport
    vec2 tex_coords = vec2(
        (gl_FragCoord.x - 100) / (screen_width / 5),
        (gl_FragCoord.y - (screen_height - (screen_height / 5) - 100)) / (screen_height / 5)
    );

    //retrieve depth value from the red channel
    float red_channel = texture(shadow_tex, tex_coords).r;

    //colorize depth value, only if there actually is an object
    if (red_channel < 0.999) {
        red_channel = linearize_depth(red_channel) * 4.0;
    }
    color = vec4(vec3(red_channel), 1.0);
}
```

[image: screenshot - kind of working]

I would still like clarification though if accessing the red component is correct to retrieve the depth value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GLSL 4.30?

#### No.

If this is truly a depth texture (internal format = `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT[...]`), then GLSL automatically samples it this way: `vec4 (r, r, r, 1.0)`. Older versions would behave differently depending on the "depth texture mode" (which was removed from GL 3.1 / GLSL 1.30).

Now, if it is a depth texture with comparison as your code implies, then sampling it using `sampler2D` should be undefined. If you use `sampler2DShadow` though, sampling with `texture (...)` will return a ***single*** `float` unlike all other `texture (...)` overloads (which all return `vec4`).

Hopefully this is an oversight in the Java code you pasted, because your shader should be producing undefined results as it stands right now.

Comment: Ah, maybe I have not been clear enough in my code, I use `compareMode(GL_NONE)` before actually taking values from the sampler, does that clarify things?

Comment: Yeah, that helps a lot.